# how to update django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I have an app named polls in Project A,and it's in admin too, but I added an app named pingpong later, I added the app pingpong in the installed_app and synced database(it works), but the admin page is still the same. So how do I do to make the admin page update?

Comment: Please show your `pingpong/admin.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your models in admin.py

```
from pingpong.models import YourModel
admin.site.register(YourModel)
```